# MySQL: how to insert only if update fails

Tags: mysql, upsert

There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52283031/running-a-mysql-insert-when-update-fails), but my requirement is **different**.

The table schema is:

```
CREATE TABLE `device` (
  `id` int NOT NULL,
  `device_type` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `serial` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `revoked` bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `created` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`serial`,`revoked`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

I want to insert into the table with a pair of `(id, serial)`, if **neither** of `id` or `serial` appears in the table.

So, I think I might do this:

```
UPDATE device SET updated='<current-time>' WHERE id='<device_id>' OR 
serial='<serial_no>' ON UPDATE FAIL INSERT (id,serial,...) VALUES (...)
```

The **ON UPDATE FAIL...** part is hypothetical.  I know that MySQL does not have this syntax.  So I want a **transactional** way to accomplish this.

Note that the PRIMARY KEY cannot be modified, although adding other indexes is allowed, without change business logic, of course.

Comment: *So, I think I might do this* Do you mean that if both `id` and `serial` values interferes in different rows and/or if specified value can be found in the same column in more than one row (these columns aren't unique) then all matched rows should be updated?

Comment: Provide a short list of id and serial values.  Then show a few samples and say which should or should not be inserted.  (There are too many ways to misinterpret what you have said so far.)

Answer (score 0):

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE update_or_insert (in_id INT, in_serial VARCHAR(128))
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS ( SELECT NULL 
                FROM device 
                WHERE id = in_id OR serial = in_serial ) THEN
        UPDATE device 
        SET updated = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
        WHERE id = in_id OR serial = in_serial;
    ELSE 
        INSERT INTO device (id, serial, revoked) 
        VALUES (in_id, in_serial, 0);
    END IF;
END
```

Of course this SP cannot perform batch inserts. If you need in this then you may provide values arrays in JSON or CSV, parse them to separate values and insert value-by-value.

Comment: I do not want to use SP, unless it can be a "lambda" function, i.e. I define an SP on-the-fly, and run it, then it is removed automatically...

Comment: @xrfang ? What is the reason? SP is called by the same way like common INSERT or UPDATE query, no difference. And if this operation is not one-time one then storing this SP in the database (working or service) is reasonable. But if you don't want to use SP nevertheless then execute the query from IF condition, analyze the output then execute INSERT or UPDATE depends on the output - and do this everything in single transaction.

Comment: I simply do not want to have any SP, trigger, function, what-so-ever, for maintenance reason.  Everything has to be in the code itself.  This is an opinioned choice.  But anyway your solution might be helpful for others having similar needs.   @Akina